# Member function of return type char* returns address that contains different string after while loop

Tags: c++

My code reads input from a text file word by word and instantiates an object for each token. In the while loop, when I call `get_value()` on the `VAR` object and dereference it I get the string `"foo"` which is what I want, but outside of the loop I get the string belonging to the `STRING` object `"HELLO"`. I'm pretty sure calling the constructor for `STRING` is what's causing the issue but I can't pin point the problem.

`STRING` and `VAR` have their own `get_value()`member function and they do not inherent from each other.
I even dynamically allocated memory in `VAR`'s `set_value()` function so I'm pretty sure `STRING()` is not mutating anything. Excuse me if I posted too much.

Output

```
$ ./venom
0x7ffeeb3a02d8
foo
0x7ffeeb3a02f8
0x7ffeeb3a02d8
Hello
Hello
```

main.cpp

```
ifstream in("new.vnm");
string s;
STRING *ptr1;
VAR    *ptr2;

    while(in >> s){
        if(s[0] == '"') {
                        //Address to (H)ello
            STRING str(&s[1]);

            ptr1 = &str;

            //0x7ffeeb3a02f8 -- That's OK
            cout << ptr1 << endl;
        }
        else if((s[0] > 'a' && s[0] < 'z') || (s[0] >'A' && s[0] < 'Z')) {
                    //Address to (f)oo
            VAR var(&s[0]);

            ptr2 = &var;

            // 0x7ffeeb3a02d8 -- This is OK.
            cout << ptr2 << endl;

            // Value stored at ptr2 -- Prints foo -- That's OK.
            for(int i = 0; ptr2->get_value()[i]; i ++)
                cout << ptr2->get_value()[i];
            cout << endl;
        }
    };

    // 0x7ffeeb3a02d8 -- That's OK
    cout << ptr2 << endl;


    // Printing Value stored at ptr2 -- Hello -- This is NOT OK!
    for(int i = 0; ptr2->get_value()[i]; i ++)
        cout << ptr2->get_value()[i];
    cout << endl;

    // Printing Value stored at ptr1 -- That's OK.
    for(int i = 0; ptr1->get_value()[i]; i ++)
        cout << ptr1->get_value()[i];
    cout << endl;
```

VAR.cpp

```
void VAR::set_name(char *name) {
    this->name = new char[this->len+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        this->name[i] = name[i];
    this->name[this->len+1] = '\0';
};

char *VAR::get_value() const {
    return this->name;
};
```

STRING.cpp

```
char *STRING::get_value() const {

    return this->value;
};

void STRING::set_value(char *str) {
    this->value = new char[this->len + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < this->len; i ++) 
        this->value[i] = str[i];
    this->value[this->len + 1] = '\0';
};
```

new.vnm (text file)

```
foo = "Hello";
```

`ptr2->get_value()` should point to `foo` not `Hello`.

Comment: for `new char[this->len + 1]` the last allowed index is `this->len`, so `this->name[this->len+1] = '\0';` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the loop both `ptr2` and `ptr1` point to objects which no longer exist - they were already destroyed, because their scope was smaller. This is undefined behaviour and a serious error. In this case anything can happen and it's a lot of luck your program only prints not what you expect instead of just crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking a pointer to a locally scoped object, and then dereferencing that pointer after the object has gone out of scope. That's undefined behaviour.

Essentially your code is this

```
VAR *ptr2;
{
    VAR var;
    ptr2 = &var;
}
ptr2->get_value() // this is invalid because 'var' no longer exists.
```